# Scalac restrictions on value classes for implicits on traits with type parameters

Tags: scala

The following does not compile because of `extends AnyVal` as it gives the following compilation error:

```
value class needs to have exactly one val parameter
```

Here's the code (simplified):

```
sealed trait Thing[A] {
  // stuff
}

object RichThing {
  implicit final class Implicits[A: ClassTag](val thing: A) extends AnyVal {

    def doSomething[B: ClassTag](f: A => B): Thing[A] = {
      // use f internally
    }
  }
}
```

The thing is that I cannot touch the library that `Thing[A]` is in and I'm trying to extend it so that for our internal users the additional functions feel seamless as per usual for implicit conversions.

I can remove `AnyVal` but is there a way around that restriction for my case (in 2.11)?

Comment: No, a value class is a wrapper around a single/scalar value, if not then that's a plain class (for which the same optimisation are not applicable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A value class must have only one argument, and your `Implicits` class has two: the explicit `val thing: A` and an implicit one with type `ClassTag[A]` coming from the context bound `[A: ClassTag]`.

To satisfy the value class requirement, you can move the implicit parameter `ClassTag[A]` from the context bound to individual functions signatures:

```
implicit final class Implicits[A](val thing: A) extends AnyVal {
  def doSomething[B: ClassTag](f: A => B)(implicit tagA: ClassTag[A]): Thing[A] = {
    // use f internally
  }
}
```

You are using this class just to provide rich methods, so it doesn't really matter at what point the implicits get injected.

Of course, you can just remove `extends AnyVal`, but then an actual `Implcits` object will be instantiated for every `doSomething` invocation, which is just needless pessimization.